# Changing Qt Scale Factor

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'd like to change my Qt app's scale based on the resolution of my devices screen. I'm trying to determine the resolution of the device and set

```
QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling); // DPI support
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps); // HiDPI pixmaps
qputenv("QT_SCALE_FACTOR", scaleAsQByteArray);
```

before my QApplication is initialized, scaleAsQByteArray to 1 if it's around the size where my app looks decent, and > 1 depending on the difference between my intended resolution and the large display resolution of the current device.

This doesn't seem to be possible, at least from what I understand, as you need an initialized QApplication to get screen information, but I also can't use qputenv after that happens.

Does anyone have a solution for how I could go about setting the scale factor of a QApplication based on screen resolution? Or to simplify things, how to get the height and width of the device monitor before I initialize the QApplication window.

I was thinking about using a Scale {} in qml: hiding the main Window and showing the scaled version instead, though this might have some performance drawbacks, but that's basically what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

I think I found a cheeky solution here. I ended up creating a throwaway QApplication just to get the width of the display, then set the scale factor and create the actual QApplication.

```
QApplication* temp = new QApplication(argc, argv);
QRect screenGeometry = QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry();
double width = screenGeometry.width();
// assumes that the default desktop resolution is 720p (scale of 1)
int minWidth = 1280;
delete temp;

double scale = width / minWidth;
std::string scaleAsString = std::to_string(scale);
QByteArray scaleAsQByteArray(scaleAsString.c_str(), scaleAsString.length());
qputenv("QT_SCALE_FACTOR", scaleAsQByteArray);

QApplication app(argc, argv);
```

The app I'm work on has a ton of hard-sized objects, and I don't have the time to change everything to use layouts, so this is a great solution so far. Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Is it possible to set QT_SCALE_FACTOR after instantiating QApplication? For instance when the user can configure the scaling without need to restart the application.

Comment: dont think so, no

Comment: Clever.  Creates a dummy app that CAN create QWidget-derived classes before instantiating the app proper, deletes it, and then constructs the app proper.  I named mine `dummyApp` for clarity.  This way, we don't need to do Windows-dependent calls.